# Byte array gets truncated when writing to memory of RFID tag using Adafruit PN532 library

Tags: python, nfc, rfid, mifare, adafruit

I'm trying to write a byte array that was converted from a hex string into the memory of an NTAG203 RFID tag. I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3, a PN532 chip and the [Adafruit PN532 python library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_PN532).

```
hex_string = '59e7168f267df300018e15b0'
formatted_hex = bytearray.fromhex(hex_string)

byte_data = bytearray(16)
byte_data[3:15] = formatted_hex

if not pn532.mifare_classic_write_block(4, byte_data):
    print('Error! Failed to write to the card.')
    sys.exit(-1)
```

When I do `pn532.mifare_classic_read_block(4)` to read the value from memory again it comes out like this:

```
print '0x{0}'.format(binascii.hexlify(<function call result>))
>>> 0x00000059440300fe0000000000000000
```

The value is chopped off and has trailing and leading zeroes. What is happening here?

I would like to be able to convert the value back into hex again to use it to search a database.

Comment: What do you expect `pn532.mifare_classic_read_block(4)` to return?

Comment: The documentation says:
"If the block is successfully read a bytearray of length 16 with data starting at the specified block will be returned."

Comment: Have you checked `type(<function call result>)` and `len(<function call result>)`?  maybe you aren't reading  successfully or you are reading the wrong block or you didn't write correctly.

Comment: I got <type 'str'> and 34.
Maybe the library is for MiFare cards only and block 4 on the NTAG203 is in a different position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, functions named `mifare_classic_*` might not be well suited for accessing NTAG203 tags since MIFARE Classic and NTAG203 use deviating framing and command sets.

However, the PN532 abstracts access to MIFARE Classic tags using a command set that is somewhat supported by NTAG203 tags. More specifically,

- the READ commands are identical (both read 16 bytes of data starting at a given block number). The only difference is the memory organization on NTAG203 compared to MIFARE Classic. While MIFARE Classic has 16 bytes per block, NTAG203 only has 4 bytes per block. As a result, the READ command returns 4 consecutive blocks.
- the MIFARE Classic WRITE command is supported as COMPATIBILITY WRITE c command by NTAG203. The only difference is that you can only write 4 bytes (one block) on NTAG203. Thus, since you still have to provide 16 bytes of data in the write command, only the first 4 bytes are written.

And this is exactly what you observed: `pn532.mifare_classic_write_block(4, byte_data)` writes only the first 4 bytes of `byte_data` to block 4. Note that the first 4 bytes are `00 00 00 59` since you copy `formatted_hex` to the slice `3:15` and leave bytes 0..2 at their default value of 0. Since the READ command reads 16 bytes (4 blocks with 4 bytes each), the read data also contains some old memory content for blocks 5..7: `440300fe0000000000000000`. That value looks reasonable since that matches the initial memory contents that's factory programmed on NTAG203.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help! So to be able to write a bytearray with the length of 12 to memory I would have to use the COMPATIBILITY WRITE command 3 times with 4 bytes each time? How do I specify which block to write to, is that what the 4 in the function call stands for?

Comment: @Sai Correct. You would call the write method for each block. The first argument of `pn532.mifare_classic_write_block()` (4 in the code above) is the block number.